# Could not find "store"

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

The error :

> Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(App)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(App)".

I believe it is an issue with the  export statement at the end.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { addReminder } from '../actions';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        text: ''
    }
  }

  addReminder(){
    console.log('this', this);
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <div className="title">
          Reminder Pro
        </div>
        <div className="form-inline">
          <div className="form-group">
              <input
              className="form-control"
              placeholder="I have too.."
              onChange={event => this.setState({text: event.target.value})}
              />
          </div>
          <button
              type="button"
              className="btn btn-success"
              onClick= {() => this.addReminder()}
          >
          add a reminder     </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return bindActionCreators({addReminder}, dispatch);
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps) (App);
```

Comment: you probably forgot to use `Provider` component on top of your components and pass `store`.

Comment: Have you wrapped your app in a provider and passing the store to it in index.js?
<Provider store={myStore}><App /></Provider>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you forgot to use [`Provider`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#provider-store) component from `react-redux`. Something like this:

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import reducers from './reducers';

const store = createStore(reducers);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App /> // here is your App component that is connected
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
)
```